# Insert data in table using csv in django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am newbie in Django and wanted to know a basic thing:

I have 2 model :

```
class QuizCat(models.Model):

    cid = models.IntegerField()
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Quiz(models.Model):

    Qid = models.IntegerField()
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey(QuizCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to insert data in database using 1 `csv` file such that data gets inserted in both QuizCat model and Quiz model. also what should be the structure of `csv` file ?

Comment: I think this is not possible using one CSV, as you have ForeignKey relation

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to add id field it will be added by django by default

**models.py**

```
class QuizCat(models.Model):
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey(QuizCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
def uploadFile(request):
    try:
        csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]#change csv_file according to your form input name
        file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")     
        lines = file_data.split("\n")
        for line in lines:                      
            fields = line.split(",")
            fields = [i.trim() for i in fields ]
            name = fields[0]
            cat = fields[1]
            qcat,created=QuizCat.objects.get_or_create(c_name=cat)
            Quiz.objects.get_or_create(cat_id=qcat,name=name)
    except e:
        raise
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

**CSV**

Quiz name,QuizCat name